# Share typescript module between multiple projects

Tags: typescript, node-modules, tsc, tsconfig-paths

I am using the TS `paths` approach to include the `shared` folder in my API project.

Here's a piece of my API's `tsconfig.json` file:

[image]

The challenge here is that the `shared` folder has its own dependencies and `package.json`

The overall project structure looks like this:

```
api/
   .../package.json
shared/
   .../package.json
```

When compiling API, my `dist` folder includes the `shared` folder definitions, but it ignores the `node_modules` therefore fails during runtime.

[image]

Question: How can I tell `tsc` compiler to include `node_modules` into `dist/shared`?

Or should I create a `post-compile` step to manually copy it? (doesn't sound clean)

Comment: I suppose you should turn `shared` folder into package and add it as a local package into your package.json.

Comment: And of course you should build it every time it changed

Comment: sounds like a lot of additional manual steps to have it as a standalone package? is there an easier approach?

Comment: Also, with the approach, you're suggesting, I'll need to do `npm install` every time I make changes to `shared` package?

Comment: Something like this, yes. `Node_modules` folder for this module does not change automatically if you change a content of `shared` module. So after some changes You should manually do `npm install/update` in the `shared` folder, right?